# GMB Patch local post add or delete image

Tags: google-my-business-api

I wanted to edit (PATCH) local posts add/delete photos
how change data/updateMask to add many media in one time or delete one of them?

links to docs
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.localPosts/patch
https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/posts-data#edit_posts

i try change updateMask to media and send array of all media adding one with my URL but respond is BAD_REQUEST message Too many photos. A post may only have a maximum of 1 photos. but on google can add 10 pic...

Working request to replace all media in local post

```
PATCH https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/*/locations/*/localPosts/*?updateMask=media.mediaFormat,media.sourceUrl
```

```
const payload = { media: [{ mediaFormat: "PHOTO", sourceUrl: "URL" }] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote in support of GMB. Bad news for us. Here is their response.

> Unfortunately, the Google Business Profile API doesn’t currently allow
> multiple photos per post. A post may only have a maximum of 1 photo.
> We’ll announce any changes or new features of the Google Business
> Profile API when they become available on the Google Developers site.
>
> Sincerely, Shalini
>
> The Google Business Profile API team

Answer (score 0):

`media` is of type array, you can just add more elements to it.

```
"media": [
    {
      object (MediaItem)
    }
]
```

To update the whole array, the `updateMask` should just be `media`.

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.localPosts#resource:-localpost

Comment: According to google support, adding more media (>1) is now not possible. Although is it array. There can only be one element in the media array.